# How to implement 2-way bindings in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I understand that we can pass props from a parent component to the child component. In my case, I am passing from App.js ( parent component) to child component - UserInput.js. However, I also want to pass the props back from UserInput.js to App.js so that I can reset the label values.
However, I am unable to do so.  When I do  props.reset(), it says reset is not a function. I get exception - typeError- "prop.reset is not a function". My ultimate goal is to reset the userName and age field to blank.

Here is my App.js and UserInput.js

```
import "./App.css";
import UserInput from "./Components/UserInput/UserInput";
import Validation from "./Components/Validation/Validation";
import { useState } from "react";
import Output from "./Components/Output/Output";


const App = (props) =>
{

  const errorMessage = [
    "",
    "Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values).",
    "Please enter a valid age (>0)."
  ];

  let usrList = [

  ];

  const [errNumber, setErrNumber] = useState(0);

  const [userList, setUsrList] = useState(usrList);

  const validationOkHandler = () => {
       //setting error back to 0.
       setErrNumber(0);
  }


  const userInputHandler = (userData) => {
    //console.log(userData);
    if (userData.user.trim() === "" || userData.age === 0) {
      console.log(
        "Invalid Input - Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values)."
      );
      setErrNumber(1);
      
    }

    else if (userData.age < 0) {
      console.log("Invalid input  Please enter a valid age (>0).");
      setErrNumber(2);
    } 
    else {
      props.reset();
      setErrNumber(0);
      userData.id = Math.random();
      setUsrList( (previousUSer) => {
        return [userData, ...previousUSer];
      }); 
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <UserInput
        onUserInput={userInputHandler}
        valdiationOk={validationOkHandler}

      />
      {errNumber > 0 && (
        <Validation valdiationOk={validationOkHandler}>
          {errorMessage[errNumber]}
        </Validation>
      )}

      {errNumber === 0 && <Output userList={userList} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my UserInput.js

```
import { useState } from "react";

import styles from "./UserInput.module.css";
import App from "../../App";


const UserInput = (props) => {
  const [usrName, setUsrName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  const userNameHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setUsrName(event.target.value);
  };

  const ageHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
      setUsrName('');
  };

  const addUserHandler = (event) => {
    const userInfo = {
      user: usrName,
      age: +age,
    };

    console.log(userInfo);
    event.stopPropagation();
    props.onUserInput(userInfo);
    <App reset={resetForm} />

  };

  const ModalHandler = () => {
    console.log("Modal handler clicked");
    props.valdiationOk();
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles["container"]}`} onClick={ModalHandler}>
      <div className={`${styles["inputWrapper"]}`}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          id="username"
          onChange={userNameHandler}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className={`${styles["inputWrapper"]}`}>
        <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" name="age" id="age" onChange={ageHandler}></input>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addUserHandler}>
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserInput;
```

Comment: In React data flows from top to bottom. You can't pass props from child to parent component. What you can do is lift the state up in the parent component and pass the relevant data to the child component as props and also define the `reset` function in parent component.

Comment: Move `useState` or similar as far up as they need to be, pass down resetting function. If it's significantly deep, use react contexts

Comment: [React - Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for props to invoke a function from another functional component in this case. You can plainly pass the `resetForm` as a callback argument to the `onUserInput` prop function along with `userInfo`, this argument function can then be directly invoked based on your checks and conditions. If you implement this you might still not see the form fields reset to empty strings `""` when the form is valid, because there's no two-way binding established between the state variable and the input fields value. To get things work as expected, you should establish this binding by setting the fields value to the hook's state variable, so that the value in the field is the same as the value of the state variable.
Your updated code should be something like this:
**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import UserInput from "./Components/UserInput/UserInput";
import Validation from "./Components/Validation/Validation";
import { useState } from "react";
import Output from "./Components/Output/Output";


const App = (props) =>
{

  const errorMessage = [
    "",
    "Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values).",
    "Please enter a valid age (>0)."
  ];

  let usrList = [

  ];

  const [errNumber, setErrNumber] = useState(0);

  const [userList, setUsrList] = useState(usrList);

  const validationOkHandler = () => {
       //setting error back to 0.
       setErrNumber(0);
  }


  const userInputHandler = (userData,reset) => { //reset is the callback function
    //console.log(userData);
    if (userData.user.trim() === "" || userData.age === 0) {
      console.log(
        "Invalid Input - Please enter a valid name and age (non-empty values)."
      );
      setErrNumber(1);
      
    }

    else if (userData.age < 0) {
      console.log("Invalid input  Please enter a valid age (>0).");
      setErrNumber(2);
    } 
    else {
      reset(); //Call reset function from the function argument as a callback function
      setErrNumber(0);
      userData.id = Math.random();
      setUsrList( (previousUSer) => {
        return [userData, ...previousUSer];
      }); 
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <UserInput
        onUserInput={userInputHandler}
        valdiationOk={validationOkHandler}

      />
      {errNumber > 0 && (
        <Validation valdiationOk={validationOkHandler}>
          {errorMessage[errNumber]}
        </Validation>
      )}

      {errNumber === 0 && <Output userList={userList} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**UserInput.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";

import styles from "./UserInput.module.css";


const UserInput = (props) => {
  const [usrName, setUsrName] = useState("");
  const [age, setAge] = useState("");

  const userNameHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setUsrName(event.target.value);
  };

  const ageHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  const resetForm = () => {
      setUsrName('');
  };

  const addUserHandler = (event) => {
    const userInfo = {
      user: usrName,
      age: +age,
    };

    console.log(userInfo);
    event.stopPropagation();
    props.onUserInput(userInfo,resetForm); //Pass resetfrom function as the callback function.
  };

  const ModalHandler = () => {
    console.log("Modal handler clicked");
    props.valdiationOk();
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles["container"]}`} onClick={ModalHandler}>
      <div className={`${styles["inputWrapper"]}`}>
        <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          id="username"
          value = {usrName} //Two way binding using the value attribute.
          onChange={userNameHandler}
        ></input>
      </div>

      <div className={`${styles["inputWrapper"]}`}>
        <label htmlFor="age">Age</label>
        <input type="text" value={age} name="age" id="age" onChange={ageHandler}></input>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button type="submit" onClick={addUserHandler}>
          Add User
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserInput;
```